# How would a human society be different from ours if our feet were also hands?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, humans, alternate-history, alternate-reality

What if we could use our feet as hands, with the same dexterity. Assume for the purposes of this question that the lower hand is structurally the same as our existing hands. Also assume that our planet's environment, gravity, structure, ecology, flora, fauna and so forth are also otherwise exactly the same.

Would we still walk upright? Would we live in trees or tree-like buildings? Would this have significantly altered history? At which points? How would our society be organized? Our cities? What do you think would be the most significant change?

As the potential answers for these multiple questions may be rather broad, please choose one aspect to focus on, the one you think most important and significant, and answer that specific question-aspect in a few paragraphs.

Comment: This is such a bizarre idea I'm having trouble determining if this might be too broad. +1, just for the sheer originality!

Comment: This might turn out to be a very broad answer, as having hands for feet probably would have had drastic implications for our evolution as a species. The simple fact that we evolved feet instead is proof of that. That said, there may be some very interesting answers.

Comment: It's been done in quite a few science fiction settings. Either our monkeys uplifted to sentience or aliens with 4 grasping limbs. Planet of the Apes and the Uplift Saga are two that spring to mind immediately.

Comment: As well, in Aeon Flux, they can be purchased as enhancements.

Comment: I use my toes to pick stuff up all the time. Drives my wife nuts.

Comment: It's probably not worth an answer, but biggest change I can think of, is shoes wouldn't be much of a thing, except in areas and jobs where it is hazardous to walk barefoot.

Comment: Joze you may be best off narrowing your scope a little bit...for example How would having four hands alter home life and design?

Comment: I surrender! make it quick lying down like this kills.

Comment: The Vorkosigan universe by Louis McMaster Bujold has a sub-species called "Quaddies" ambulating throughout her various books. They even get at least one book of their own, if I recall correctly. This explores one possible society.

Answer (score 1):

The first difference is that we would not be able to walk far, or well.  The main difference between hominids and other apes is a specialization for fully erect, long duration walking on the ground. This caused the loss of most dexterity on the foot.

A human that specialized the other way would have more mobile hips, knees and legs but ones not as suitable for walking and running on level ground.  So it would be a profound difference that would likely lead to the proto-humans remaining a localized species and not spreading world wide.